# Error with mono profiler in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mono, profiling

I tried to run mono profiler as is explained [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Profiler), but I got this error message.

```
ver6> mono --profile=log program.exe 
Error loading profiler module 'mono-profiler-log': dlopen(libmono-profiler-log.bundle, 9): image not found
```

Is this a mono bug?

My OS X version is 10.6.7, and I use mono 2.10.2.

### SOLVED

After adding the `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.2/lib` path to .bashrc `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.2/lib"`, the problem is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either don't have that file installed or you need to set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH env var to point to the directory where it is located. Look for libmono-profiler-log.dylib, the .bundle extension is a fallback.